# Number of cores by default Spark local mode takes

Tags: apache-spark

What will be the number of cores the executor takes when spark is run in local mode and also if I don't mention number of cores in command as below

```
./start-shell --master local
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the answer for my question and I just wanted to put it here.
If user mentions just "local" without specifying any number of cores, it just takes only 1 core.

If its "local[N]", takes N cores
If its "local[*]", takes all the cores available.

Comment: This also works to limit the number of python pyspark.daemon processes.